# How to I add a new file in a directory that's not the current one I'm in (via keyboard, not with mouse)?

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say I have:

```
lib
|
---a
   |
    --a_1.txt
|
---b
   |
    --b_1.txt
```

If I'm currently in `a_1.txt`, how can I create `b_2.txt` in `lib/b/`? If I use `CMD + N`, I can only add a file to `lib/a/`. The only way I can find to do so is by opening the side panel (which I like closed), and  right clicking `lib/b/`, then adding a new file there. Is there a easier way to do this via the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Project` tab using the shortcut (`ctrl + 1` on Windows) then using keyboard move to the directory that you want to create a new file.
After that using `Generated Code` shortcut (`alt + Insert` in Windows) to create a new file that your want